# Prime ideals definition

Tags: ring-theory

If $A,~B$ are two ideals of a ring $R$ and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ such that  $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$ . Does this implies to $AB\subseteq P$?
i.e. Does the result true since $P$ is prime?

Comment: Yes, because $AB\subset A$ and $AB\subset B$.

Comment: The *definition* of prime ideals says that **if** $AB\subseteq P$, **then** $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$.  You appear to be asking about the converse of a portion of the definition, not the definition itself.

Comment: Said another way, when you wrote "we have," I hope you do not think that the definition of "prime ideal" entails that the prime ideal must contain one of any pair of ideals in the ring.

Comment: This is also a good example of how your question could be clearer with a better title and more context. As it's written, it looks like you might be misunderstanding the definition. On the other hand, you might understand the definition and you are asking about a converse of part of it, which isn't that unnatural. But right now it's hard to understand what you want because the title is so weak and the question contains so little context.

Answer (score 4):

If $A \subset P$ or $B \subset P$ then
$$
AB \subset A \subset P \quad\text{ or } \quad AB \subset B \subset P.
$$
The ideal $P$ does not need to be prime.

Answer (score 2):

By hypothesis,  $A \subset P$ or $B \subset P$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $A \subset P$. Let $x = ab \in AB$. As $a \in P$ and $b \in B \subset R$ and $P$ is a ideal of $R$, we have $ab \in P$. Actually, P does not have to be a prime ideal of $R$.